How can I capture the thumbnail after the recorded video has loaded? (using React JS)
I am recording the video using a preview via videoPreviewRef. After the recorded video is displayed on the videoLiveRef video element, I need to capture a thumbnail image from the recorded video using videoLiveRef. However, I only get a black image instead of the actual video thumbnail.
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import { ColumnCenter } from '@/components/ui/Column';

type VideoPreviewProps = {
  blobUrl?: string;
  stream?: MediaStream;
  setThumbnailFile: any;
};

export const VideoPreview = ({
  blobUrl,
  stream,
  setThumbnailFile,
}: VideoPreviewProps) => {
  const videoLiveRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const videoPreviewRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef<any>(null);
  //const getFileCalled = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (blobUrl && videoLiveRef.current && videoPreviewRef.current) {
      videoLiveRef.current.srcObject = null;
      videoLiveRef.current.src = blobUrl;
    }
  }, [blobUrl]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (videoPreviewRef.current && stream && stream.active) {
      videoPreviewRef.current.srcObject = stream;
      videoPreviewRef.current.src = '';
    }
  }, [stream]);


  const captureThumbnail = () => {
    if (blobUrl) {
      const video = videoLiveRef.current;
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;

      if (video && canvas) {
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        if (context && video.readyState > 2) {
          canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
          canvas.height = video.videoHeight;

          console.log(canvas.width, canvas.height);

          if (context) {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            canvas.toBlob(
              (blob: Blob | null) => {
                if (blob) {
                  console.log(blob);
                  setThumbnailFile(blob);
                }
              },
              'image/jpeg',
              0.5
            );
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = videoLiveRef.current;

    if (video && blobUrl) {
      video.src = blobUrl;
      if (blobUrl) {
        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', captureThumbnail);
        return () => {
          video.removeEventListener('loadedmetadata', captureThumbnail);
        };
      } else {
        console.log("blobUrl is not working");
      }
    }
  }, [blobUrl]);

  if (!blobUrl && !stream) {
    return (
      <ColumnCenter>
        <p className="w-full text-center">
          Please allow video and audio permission to begin video recording
        </p>
      </ColumnCenter>
    );
  }

  if (!blobUrl && stream && !stream.active) {
    return (
      <ColumnCenter>
        <p className="w-full text-center">
          Please click the <b className="mx-1">Start Recording</b> button to
          begin recording
        </p>
      </ColumnCenter>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={videoPreviewRef} className="w-full h-[410px] mb-3" autoPlay>
        <track kind="captions" src="" label="No captions available" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
      <div className="mx-auto w-[273.33px]">
        <video
          ref={videoLiveRef}
          className="w-full h-[205px] "
          controls
          //onLoadedMetadata={captureThumbnail}
        >
          <track kind="captions" src="" label="No captions available" />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      </div>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ display: 'none' }} />
    </div>
  );
};


i need a thumbnail image from recorded video
